# Unable to read data from a file using input file stream class in C++

Tags: c++

I've a constructor for the `Engine` class which reads in the contents of `king-moves.movelist` into a `std::map` using an input file stream. The function below illustrates the same:

```
Engine::Engine() {
    std::ifstream dbFile;
    dbFile.open( "../data/king-moves.movelist" );

    if( !dbFile )
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to read king moves" << std::endl;
    else {
        unsigned long long a, b;
        while( true ) {
            dbFile >> a >> b;
            m_k_moves_db.insert( std::pair< unsigned long long, unsigned long long >( a, b ) );
            if( dbFile.eof() ) 
                break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << m_k_moves_db.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The `Engine` class can be minimally represented as follows:

```
class Engine {
private:
    std::map< unsigned long long, unsigned long long > m_k_moves_db;

public:
    // Constructors and other functions
};
```

Now when I try to print the contents of `m_k_moves_db`, I'm met with the error message `Error: Unable to read king moves`.

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong while reading in from the file stream?

Comment: the error is reported before you even started to read from the file. Usually the cause for a file not opening correctly is that it isnt in the location you expect it to be (relative to the working directory)

Comment: Are you familiar with the development environment you're using? A lot of the time, this sort of problem is caused by the working directory not being what you expect. A quick trick that might help is, at the beginning of `main()`, to print the value of `argv[0]`

Comment: Note that you're checking `eof()` too late. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) for how to write an input loop.

Comment: A more idiomatic loop would be `while (dbFile >> a >> b) { m_k_moves_db[a] = b; }`. There is no point to using `insert` if you ignore its return value.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `std::ifstream dbFile; dbFile.open( "../data/king-moves.movelist" );` to `std::ifstream dbFile( "../data/king-moves.movelist" );`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I just wrote another program using the exact same code to test the correctness of my implementation. And everything worked as intended.  The problem seems to be something else altogether I guess!